# How Do I check there exits a same value of column ?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the code below i need to check the description must not be same so i have to check the description column for duplicate entry how to do this ?

```
        <?php
        session_start();
        require 'Admin/includes/connection.php';
        $emp_id =  $_SESSION['id'];
        $task_name = $_POST['task_name'];
        $desc = $_POST['desc'];
        $hours = $_POST['hours'];

        $t = "random";
        $a =  date('Y-m-d');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO project_task (emp_id, task_type, task, description, hours, submit_date) VALUES ('$emp_id', '$t', '$task_name', '$desc', '$hours', '$a')";

        if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
            $data["abc"] = "true"; 
        }
        else{
                $data["abc"] = "false";
        }       
        header("Content-type: application/json");
        echo json_encode($data);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Will Help You

```
<?php 
        session_start();
        require 'Admin/includes/connection.php';
        $emp_id =  $_SESSION['id'];
        $task_name = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['task_name']);
        $desc = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['desc']);
        $hours = $_POST['hours'];

        $t = "random";
        $a =  date('Y-m-d');


        $q = "SELECT description from project_task where description = '$desc' ";    
        $result = $conn->query($q);
        if($result->num_rows > 0 ){
             $data["result"] = "false";           
        }else{

            $sql = "INSERT INTO project_task (emp_id, task_type, task, description, hours, submit_date) VALUES ('$emp_id', '$t', '$task_name', '$desc', '$hours', '$a')";

            if($conn->query($sql) === TRUE){
                $data["result"] = "true";
            }
            else{
                    $data["result"] = "false";
            }       
                 }
            header("Content-type: application/json");
            echo json_encode($data);          
           ?>
```

Comment: Hold on I have to check

Comment: Ok no prblm if it work don't forgot to accept the answer